# Classification of finite groups such that every subgroup is a quotient group of the group by one of its subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $\forall H\le G$ $\exists K\le G$ such that $H\cong G/K$

What can be said about the group?

---

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group.

1. We know that any finite abelian group has the said property.
2. Let $G$ is finite non abelian group.

$S_3$ doesn't satisfy the above property as for $H=\langle (123)\rangle$ $\not\exists K\le G$ such that $H\cong S_3/K$

What I have observed that to satisfy the above property,$\forall d\mid o(G) $ there must exists $K\lhd G $ such that $o(K) =d$

But this condition is not sufficient as $H=\langle i\rangle \le Q_8$ there doesn't exists $K\le Q_8$ such that $H\cong Q_8/K$ as $Q_8$ has a unique (normal) subgroup of order $2$ , namely $Z(Q_8) $ which yields a non cyclic factor group (which is in fact isomorphic to $K_4$)

> Give an example of a non abelian group having the above property.

> What can be said about the finite group having the above property?

Comment: A quick comment: the non-abelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$ is an example.

Comment: You are asking about groups where every subgroup is isomorphic to a quotient. Similarly one could ask about groups where every quotient is isomorphic to a subgroup, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693141/classification-of-finite-groups-such-that-every-subgroup-is-a-quotient-group-of)

Comment: Just an observation: $H\cong G/K$ is true if and only if $G/K$ is a group (otherwise isomorphism doesn't make sense) if and only if $K\unlhd G$. So, in essence, by Lagrange's Theorem, if $G$ has order $n$ and $H$ has order $m\leq n$, you are asking whether there is a **normal** subgroup $K\unlhd G$ of order $\frac{n}{m}$. This seems rarely true.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if $K\unlhd G$ has order $\frac{n}{m}$, then by the same logic there must exist a normal subgroup $L\unlhd G$ of order $m$. That is, for each subgroup of $G$, there is a normal subgroup of the same order. If all subgroups are normal, and your group is not abelian, then maybe investigate the Hamiltonian Groups: https://planetmath.org/hamiltoniangroup